# How to implement a projection matrix in CSS3D

Tags: css, opengl-es, 3d, three.js

I'm playing with augmented reality in javascript (using [Chilitags](https://github.com/chili-epfl/chilitags)). I'm trying to make a 3D transformation of HTML elements, transformed with CSS3, a bit like [Three.js's CSS3d demo](http://www.mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/threejs/css3d/periodictable/), but simpler.

To do so, I detect the 3d  transformation of tags, given in the form of a 4x4 matrix. For each transformation, I create a `.tag` div containing a simple text and a background, which I transform using CSS' transform:matrix3d(...) directive.

All these `.tag` divs are contained in a `#camera` div, which is supposed to apply the projection transform. This is where I am stuck. I do not manage to find a transform:matrix3d(...); that makes the `.tag` divs overlap exactly the barcodes in the image.

So far, my closest result is with a

  `1   0 0 0
  0   1 0 0
  0   0 1 0
320 240 0 1`

projection matrix that translates the tag divs, but does not take their depth into account. The result is shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Udqu5/), where I hard coded the transformation matrices of the tags in the background sample snapshot.

I also tried with a projection matrix used to draw the tags in other demo with three.js. This matrix is a regular perspective transform, but it does not seem to work at all here. This matrix is the one commented out in the CSS.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me find a way to match the `.tag` divs on the tags on the image, i.e. cover the barcodes with the purple quadrilaterals in the jsFiddle.

Comment: do you use somewhere : perspective:(valueUnit); ?

Comment: I hadn't, assuming that I do not need to worry about perspective if I just want to overlay "flat" things on the tags, but maybe I'm just all mixed up. Anyway, I tried in the jsFiddle to add `perspective:150px;` to `#camera` and it did not seem to change anything.